# Interface is too empty

Tags: interface

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 0n my PC without any third-party software (cause i havent been able to get my dial-up to work). When i open Ubuntu after reboot, there is absolutely nothing on the desktop screen except for an 'Untitled' folder at the corner of the screen. There is no menu, no taskbars at the top whatever. I dont know why this is happening. The .iso from which i have booted amd installed Ubuntu is fine. I have already conducted an md5sum test and it was all fine. Looking forward to your response.

Comment: What are your PC's Specs?

Answer (score 0):

Log out and try logging in using the Ubuntu-2D session.

Click here:

[image: login-desktop-selection]

Select Ubuntu-2D there.

[image: 2d]

The reason might be because your graphics is not supported by Unity. If this works, install the [additional drivers](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/jockey-gtk/) required your computer and you should be on your way.